# how to hide struct member in a dll or library

Tags: c++, c, dll, directx

i am creating a library for game development, it uses directx 2d, however i want that some variables (ID2D1Factory, ID2D1HwndRenderTarget and others) be invisible to the end user. for example, the SDL library even using the directdraw (i guess), the directdraw classes are invisible for the end user of the SDL, and the user don't need to have the ddraw header in the includes folder of the compiler.

how can i turn these members independent(some way that the end user don't need to install the DirectX SDK for use my library), and turn these members invisible for the end user?

Comment: Google the `Pimpl` idiom. Or build you engine like COM is done: virtual only. Plus SDK distribution is not really necessary anymore.

Comment: Please read [Where is the DirectX SDK?](http://aka.ms/dxsdk) and [Not So DirectSetup](http://aka.ms/dxsetup) so you understand the actual reasons your users would need either the legacy DirectX SDK or the DXSETUP package. For Direct2D, they don't need either and neither do you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to install the DirectX SDK to link against a DLL .lib, or to compile with a .h, as long as you don't expose any DirectX objects (which you don't want to do).

Also SDL doesn't use DirectDraw. In fact it doesn't even exist since DirectX 7 (12 is coming out this September, so you're really out of the loop).

Comment: I think `D2D` is his `DDraw`.

Comment: It's ok if you do, but it doesn't make it true.